# ID sequence dynamic

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to create a sequence which max num is 999, but the problem that I'm facing is when I create for example 5 Id's and then I remove the 3rth one my sequence will create id 6, is there any way to trigger that avoiding empty Id's?

Example

Id used 
1 2 3 4 5
I delete the 3 one
1 2 4 5

I make an insert and the **CURRENT** result is 
1 2 4 5 6

And my **goal** is  :
1 2 3 4 5

Comment: Why is that your goal? It doesn't make a lot of sense. Before you ever add a new row (with id = 6), your data will look like 1 2 4 5. Why is that OK (apparently it is, since you are not trying to fix THAT), but 1 2 4 5 6 is not OK?

Comment: To clarify my comment: very often, smart but novice developers believe they must have sequences without gaps. That belief is not justified; it is exceptionally rare that a sequence without gaps is truly needed. Gaps are OK.

Comment: But if I create a sequence and I have only one row with id 999 and I want to create another row (I have a check that max is 999) if I create a new one Id will be 1?

Comment: You will have the same problem even if you recycle id's. What if you have 1,000 or more rows? This is why limiting your ID's to three digits is a very poor idea too. Why is it not OK for the ID to be six digits, or even 20 digits?

Answer (score 2):

If you do have a fixed number of resources to allocate (car park spaces, theatre seats, hotel rooms etc), you'd want to avoid sequences and have a table with a row for each resource.

You'd then allocate the resources using something like

```
declare
  cursor c_res is
  select id
  from resource
  where status = 'FREE'
  order by id
  for update of status;
  v_id number;
begin
  open c_res;
  fetch c_res into v_id
  update resource
  set status = 'ALLOCATED'
  where current of c_res;
  close c_res;
end;
```

You'd need to add error handling to cater for cases when you don't have any more resources available. There's also (almost inevitable) concurrency issues when dealing with a small, fixed number of resources.

Answer (score 0):

You should NEVER reuse IDs. No reason to do it, only troubles.
You can find first available ID including gaps by something like this, if you REALLY, REALLY need it. But this is wrong programming practice. Your ID has probably also real-live meaning, in such case you should not call it ID.

```
select min(t1.id+1) as gap_id
    from table t1
    left join thesametable t2 on t2.id=t1.id+1
    where t2.id is null
```